# Python Darts API

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, time-series

I'm doing some time series prediction using the [Darts](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/index.html) API in Python. I'm currently using a Recurrent Neural Network. But while reading the docs I saw a parameter named [training_length](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/generated_api/darts.models.forecasting.rnn_model.html#darts.models.forecasting.rnn_model.RNNModel.fit_from_dataset). I can't understand what it exactly changes internally in the training process of the model. The only thing I noticed is that changing this parameter to different numbers in some cases raises an exception during the training process. With the following error: '

```
ValueError: The dataset contains some time series that are too short to contain `max(self.input_chunk_length, self.shift + self.output_chunk_length)
```

Could someone help me understand exactly what this parameter does?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing some research using Darts as well. If you go the RNN documentation you will that the following description for the parameter training_length:

> training_length (int) – The length of both input (target and covariates) and output (target) time series used during training. Generally speaking, training_length should have a higher value than input_chunk_length because otherwise during training the RNN is never run for as many iterations as it will during inference. For more information on this parameter, please see darts.utils.data.ShiftedDataset

This is what is causing your error. Your input_chunk_length is bigger than your training_length. The input_chunk_length determines how much your model considers when making a prediction, it's also known as the lookback period of your model.

We also need to consider the output_chunk_length when determining the training_length. Luckily for the RNN, this parameter is always set to 1. Meaning that it performs one-step-ahead forecasting. Therefore, if you want to fix this error you should set your training_length = input_chunk_length + 1. 1 representing the output_chunk_length in this case.

So for instance, if your input_chunk_length is 21, you want to set your training_length = 22 or greater.